# How to draw a layout size in terms of % in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I wanted to draw a layout using wxpython in the size function below is the code to draw a layout how do I mention the size in terms of % (ex size=("20%","20%") or how to convert pixel in into %.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# size.py

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(250, 200))

        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Size')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the screen and calculate percentages size, since you can only specify size in pixels. so your **init** should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title, percent):

    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title)
    screen_size_x, scree_size_y = wx.GetDisplaySize()
    size_x = round(screen_size_x*percent,0)
    size_y = round(screen_size_y*percent,0)
    self.SetSize((size_x, size_y))
    self.Show()
```

And then you invoke the Example frame with
    Example(None, title='Size', percent=0.2)

Comment: Thanks.. But how to read screen size using python in dynamic way

Comment: I don't understand...please explain what do you mean by dynamic? the screen size doesn't change.

Comment: suppose If I use this script on different monitor or display automatically should detect... if this would be a very helpful... thanx

Comment: this is exactly what the script does, every time you run it it checks the monitor size, and sets the size of the windows to percentage of wiidth and height you set when you create the Example frame